# Which git command give me only merge commits for the master branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit, pull-request

I just merged PR to the master.

I want to log all the merges commits.

So which `git command` give me only **merge** commits for the *master branch*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using merges flag**

`$ git log --merges`

---

**Using grep**

```
$ git log | grep '^Merge:' -B 1 -A 5
```

This will show you a list of the merge commits

Comment: The problem with this solution is when I do "Squash and merge", it not show there. because it makes it regular commit and no `Merge` write there. any idea how to find it too?

Comment: in squash no merge commit appears you need to commit the changes manually. squash basically copy the changes in your branch and copy it to the branch you want to merge and stage the changes.
one thing you could do is adding unique text so you can grep them later.
you can add `Merge:` in your commit message and use the same command `$ git log | grep Merge: -B 1 -A 5` to get a list of all merges. squashed or not.

Comment: `git log --merges` will find all merges into all branches, not just merges into master. `git log | grep` depends on the merge message, which may not contain a merge message.

Comment: I don't understand why it's voted down. @Mort your comment is rephrasing my answer.

Comment: @TawfikNasser it's voted down because it doesn't answer the question posted. The question specifically asked to *find only merge commits for the master branch*. This answer finds merge commits for the master branch, as well as a bunch of other commits which are not merge commits to master branch.